# Flutter: how to add slide animation when selecting item in the list?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I have a list of notes in my application and I want when the user selects an item (to see full details) a slide animation will be fired (something close to [this](https://streamable.com/09a42v))

the code

```dart
SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const DisplayProfileWidget(),
              ListContainerWidget(
                child: selectedNote == null
                    ? const NotesStreamWidget() // <=== here when I display the list of the items and when clicked I set notesProvider to the selected note then the else widget displayed
                    : Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(
                            child: NoteHeaderWidget(),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: Text(
                              selectedNote.title.toUpperCase(),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

in my case I want the slide animation to start when user clicked on the item (aka update the provider) and start again but in reverse when he goes back

screenshots:

[image]

when user selects an item:
[image]